# Improper integral $-\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

If I have to solve $-\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx$ it is right to write:
$$-\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\geq \int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{-1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
and so the integral is divergent? I have use the fact that $-\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\geq \frac{-1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}$.

If I have instead $\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx$, so without minus sign, what can I do to prove the divergence? Is it true that from the following I can deduce the divergence?
$$\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx=-\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{-\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx\geq -\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{-1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx $$
My doubt arises since I have seen here that a similar integral here ([Solution verification of the improper integral $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\cos^2{t}}{t}\,dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4118171/900585)) is solved in a more complicate way...

Comment: Whether there is a minus sign in front of an integral is irrelevant to its convergence/divergence.

Comment: Ok so my idea is right and can I apply this also when I have minus or plus sign?

Comment: In this case, it just means you can't use $\sin x\le1$ as it is an upper bound rather than a lower bound. It is true that $\int_a^\infty dx/x^{1/3}=\infty$ but that tells you nothing about $\int_a^\infty\sin^4x/x^{1/3}\,dx$.

Comment: But when I have a minus sign I can wirite that the original integral is $\geq$ $\int_a^{\infty}\frac{-1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}$ so the divergence follows, right?

Comment: No. The minus sign does not change anything, as all you're saying now is that $-\int_a^\infty\sin^4x/x^{1/3}\,dx\ge-\int_a^\infty dx/x^{1/3}\ge-\infty$ and this gives no new information.

Comment: In short, the inequality $-1\le\sin x\le1$ *does not work here*.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire sorry but if I found out a lower bound that diverges is not true that the original intergral diverges?

Comment: You need a lower bound if the integral is *positive*. You need an upper bound if the integral is *negative*.

Comment: Ok so neither  if I have a plus sign can I write $\int_3^{\infty}\frac{\sin^4{t}}{t^{\frac{1}{3}}}=-\int_3^{\infty}\frac{-\sin^4{t}}{t^{\frac{1}{3}}}\geq -\int_3^{\infty}\frac{-1}{t^{\frac{1}{3}}}$? in this case I have that the integral is positive...

Comment: @TheSimpliFire so for what I have written in my last coment for the positive integral I have obtained a lower bound...it is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{2n\pi}^{2n\pi+\pi}\frac{\sin^4x}{x^{1/3}}dx\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2n\pi+\pi}}\int_{2n\pi}^{2n\pi+\pi}\sin^4xdx\\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2n\pi+\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^4xdx\\
=\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{2n\pi+\pi}}\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\sin^4xdx
=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2n\pi+\pi}}\cdot\frac{3\pi}{8}.$$
So
$$\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx\geq\frac{3\pi}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2n\pi+\pi}}=+\infty.$$

Comment: Ok thanks! And for the minus sign? I would need a lowe or an upper bound?

Comment: $\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx$ is divergent if and only if $-\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx$  is divergent.

Comment: If you know Cauchy's convergent Principle, this is enough to show your improper integral is divergent!

Comment: In fact one can stop at the first line, saying that the integral is a positive constant.

Comment: Ok but If I want to study the divergence with the minus sign I have to find out a function GREATER (and not SMALLER as in case of positive function) and negative that gives me a divergent integral?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let us avoid the confusion raised by the minus sign, using the fact that if $-I$ diverges, so does $I$.

Now

$$\frac{\sin^4x}{x^{1/3}}<\frac1{x^{1/3}}$$ is of no help because it only gives an upper bound on the function and the function could remain much smaller. What you need is a lower bound.

A correct way to solve is to write for instance

$$\frac{\sin^4x}{x^{1/3}}>\frac1{\color{red}4\,x^{1/3}}$$ which holds *in a constant fraction* of every period, and this will be enough to justify divergence.

Comment: Ok thanks I have not understand why I can't state $$\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx=-\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{-\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx\geq -\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{-1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx$$ and from which the divergence...I have found out a lower bound, not? Where I am failing?

Comment: @cely: this inequality is plain wrong. For God's sake, drop that minus sign.

Comment: mm sorry if I don't understand...why it is wrong?

Comment: $$\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx=-\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{-\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx$$ then $$\frac{-\sin^4{t}}{t^{\frac{1}{3}}}\geq \frac{-1}{t^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$ so $$-\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{-\sin^{4}{x}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx\geq  -\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{-1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx$$

Comment: Since $\sin^{4}\leq 1$ then $-\sin^{4}\geq -1$

Comment: @cely: ok. And how does this imply the third ?

Comment: oh damn it holds exactly the opposite inequality right?

Comment: Moreover the last question: I have the problem with the minus sign...I have to prove that if the function $f$ considered is negative then $\int_1^{+\infty}f(t)\, dt\leq \int_1^{+\infty}g(t)\, dt$ with $g$ neagtive and divergent. if I want the divergent of the original integral?So for negative function the comparison criterion is opposite? And so I need an upper bound instead of a lower bound?

Comment: I would say that in case of negative function I need an upper bound, am i wrong?

Comment: @cely: I said answer, not ask ;-)

Comment: I have answered but I am not sure that my answer is right... :(

Comment: Hence I should do a separate question...